# python regex sub without order

Tags: python, regex

I have following string "3 0ABC, mNone\n" and I want to remove m None and \n. The catch is that 'm', \n and None can be anywhere in the string in any order. I would appreciate any help.
I can do re.sub('[\nm,]','',string) or re.sub('None','',string) but don't know how to combine specially when the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove `m`, `None` and `\n` you can use them as pattern together in a group. So you can use this regex:

```
(m|\\n|None)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/oX0aZ7/3)**

[image]

If you use the following code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(m|\\n|None)')
test_str = u"3 0ABC, mNone\n"
subst = u""

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
print result

// Will show: 
'3 0ABC, '
```